# How do I point at a vector in another class?

Tags: c++

I have a class that holds a vector, which also inherits another class:

```
class txtExt : public extention
{
private:
   string  openedFile_;
public:
   vector<string> txtVector; //the vector i want to call
};
```

I fill the vector in a method within a class:

```
class Manager : public extention
{
   // there is some other code here that I know does work
   // and it calls this function:
   void organizeExtention(string filename, string ext)
   {
      if(ext == "txt")
      {
         txtExt txtExt;
         txtExt.txtVector.pushback(filename);
      }
   }
}
```

and this is my main class where i attempt to call the vector:

```
int main()
{
   // some code here that does previous operations like getting the path
   // and filling the vector


   // I've tried many ways of trying to call the vector
   // here is an example of one:
   vector<txtExt*> testVector;
   for(int i = 0; i < testVector.size(); ++i)
   {
      cout << testVector[i] << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I have a few questions:

1. Am I calling the vector wrong?
2. Is my vector empty?
3. Do I have to make my vector global, so other classes can see it?

Note: I've been able to print out the vector where I load the vector using a very simple for loop

Comment: You can't "call" a vector. It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `txtExt txtExt;` urgh. That's extremely confusing, at best.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as has been said you have a few errors in the code posted, and you maybe have some misunderstandings as well. But to answer the question asked, this

```
testVector[i]->txtVector
```

is the way to access the `txtVector` object that is inside each of your `txtExt` objects.

If that doesn't work for you then it's because one of the other errors/misunderstandings you have in your code.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize:

**reread the first chapters of a good C++ book ( [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) ), then try try to fix your program and deal with each error one at the time.**

There are several errors in your code.

- First of all, there's no operator `<<` for printing entities of the type txtExt*.
- Even object of type `txtExt` is not printable just like that.
- In addition, the testVector you made is empty, so no .size() will be zero, and there's going to be no looping.
- Are you really sure that you like to inherit both your classes from 'extension' ?
- You can't call a vector, you can access it.
- Having a data member (like the vector) public is not a good idea.
- Calling a variable by the same name as a class is a very bad idea.

I have trouble guessing what your code should do. Here's a simple example of things you need to understand:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class TxtExt 
{
public:
  std::vector<std::string> txtVector; 
};

int main(){
  TxtExt oneTxtExt;

  oneTxtExt.txtVector.push_back("hello");
  oneTxtExt.txtVector.push_back("world");
  for( auto &i : oneTxtExt.txtVector ){
    std::cout << i <<std::endl;
  }
}
```

The following code is correct, but has absolutely no effect. You could as well just write `{}`:

```
{
  TxtExt TxtExt;
  TxtExt.txtVector.pushback(filename);
}
```

You here create a new object, push back to it (btw it is called `push_back`), but then the object is destroyed at the end of the scope. Also, don't name you objects the same as the class, it becomes really confusing.

Comment: Is there a correct way to point at the vector in my txtExt class, so I can print it out in my main class?

Comment: My Manager class is supposed to hold all my launcher objects,
and my txtExt class is supposed to be a derived class from my base class(extention)

Comment: I guess there was no real reason to inherit from extension in Manager, it works fine without it at this point. and I meant to access the vector, not call it, my bad on that one. Kinda new to programming, don't know the exact terminology some times.

Comment: and also, I just used a ranged for, pretty much exactly as you have it there, and it didn't work.